# Why can't I access a google app engine entity's key from within my jinja template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

This should be a simple one.  I am building a google app engine app.  It makes a list of forms dyanmically using a list of entities called blocks.  The blocks have various properties, the labels on the radio buttons, the size of the text area, that kind of thing.  I iterate over a list of these blocks in a jinja template, picking out the particulars of the form from the properties of that particular block.  That all works fine.

However, I would like to include a unique identifier for the block entity that I am using to build the form within the form.  That will give me an efficient way of knowing what my user is responding to when he sends me a response.

I tried:

> ```
> <form>
>     <input type="hidden" name="qKey" value="{{block.id}}">
> ```

That returns the following to my browser:

> ```
> <form>
>     <input type="hidden" name="qKey" value="">
> ```

Then I tried:

> ```
>     <form>
>         <input type="hidden" name="qKey" value="{{block.key}}">
> ```

That returned:

> ```
> <form>
>     <input type="hidden" name="qKey" value="<bound method Block.key of <dynamicsurvey2.Block object at 0x10a092f10>>">
> ```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jinja2 doesn't automatically call functions for you, and `.key()` is a function, not a property.

Instead of `{{block.key}}` you need to use `{{block.key()}}` to actually call the function and get the return value.